# how to combine Jdbi @GeneratedKeys with @RegisterMapper

Tags: jdbi

```
@RegisterMapper(PhoneNumberMapper.class)
public interface PhoneNumberJdbiDAO
{
    @Transaction
    @GetGeneratedKeys(columnName = "ID", value = OracleGeneratedKeyMapper.class)
    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO PHONE_NUMBER (ID, COUNTRY_CODE_ISO2, PHONE_NUMBER, CREATE_DATETIME, UPDATE_DATETIME) " +
           "VALUES (PHONE_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :countryCode, :phoneNumber, :createDateTime, :updateDateTime)")
    PhoneNumber save(@BindBean PhoneNumber phoneNumber);
}
```

Can the `OracleGeneratedKeyMapper.class` and `PhoneNumberMapper.class` co-exist to return the mapped bean? When I execute this, `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to me.nave.persistence.domain.PhoneNumber` is being thrown.

The intent is to return a bean with the generated ID.

The PhoneNumberMapper

```
public class PhoneNumberMapper implements org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.ResultSetMapper<PhoneNumber>
{
    @Override
    public PhoneNumber map(int index, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException
    {
        CountryCode countryCodeIso2 = CountryCode.getByCodeIgnoreCase(rs.getString("COUNTRY_CODE_ISO2"));

        DateTime phoneNumberCreateDatetime =
            new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("CREATE_DATETIME").getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);

        DateTime phoneNumberUpdateDatetime =
            new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("UPDATE_DATETIME").getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC);

        return new PhoneNumber
            .Builder(countryCodeIso2, rs.getString("PHONE_NUMBER"))
            .id(rs.getBigDecimal("ID"))
            .createDateTime(phoneNumberCreateDatetime)
            .updateDateTime(phoneNumberUpdateDatetime)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Here is the OracleGeneratedKeyMapper.

```
public class OracleGeneratedKeyMapper implements org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.ResultSetMapper<BigDecimal>
{
    @Override
    public BigDecimal map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException
    {
        return r.getBigDecimal(1);
    }
}
```

The table and Sequences

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "PHONE_NUMBER_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE "TEST"."PHONE_NUMBER"
(     "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL,
      "COUNTRY_CODE_ISO2" VARCHAR2(2 CHAR) NOT NULL,
      "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL,
      "CREATE_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
      "UPDATE_DATETIME" TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PHONE_NUMBER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Comment: can you share the implementation of PhoneNumberMapper and OracleGeneratedKeyMapper ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Manikandan, updated the question with Mapper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mapper and @RegisterMapper is not used while getting inserted id back. If you want PhoneNumber object (with id alone) to be returned after insert, You can use following mapper.

```
public class PhoneNumberIdMapper implements org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.ResultSetMapper<BigDecimal>
{
  @Override
  public BigDecimal map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException
  {
    return new PhoneNumber(r.getBigDecimal(1));
  }
}
```

But if you are looking to get the whole PhoneNumber object, we need to do it manually. I could think of two options,

```
public abstract PhoneNumber savePhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    BigDecimal id = save(phoneNumber);
    phoneNumber.setId(id)
}
```

Or read it from DB again.

```
public abstract PhoneNumber savePhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    BigDecimal id = save(phoneNumber);
    getPhoneNumber(id); // reading it from DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was actually trying to see if I was missing something in my implementation. The documentation on JDBI is sparse.

Comment: @NaveenBabuE We are in the process of updating our documentation for JDBI v3 (for Java 8). Please submit an issue to the project and let us know about any topics that need better documentation. github.com/jdbi/jdbi